# Where to store RSA private key for windows application?

Tags: windows, security, key, rsa

We have a windows application that generates signatures to authenticate itself to a remote server. It uses RSA to generate the signature. What would be a recommended secure location on the windows machine to keep the private key?

Comment: Best to assume there's nowhere that's "secure" on a Windows machine, and come up with a system that doesn't depend on it.

Comment: Windows has built-in cryptographic functions, you can use the [CryptoAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the [CNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Both include functions for storage of keys and certificates.  It would also be much safer to use one of these APIs to generate your private key and to do the signing, rather than writing your own code.  Implementing cryptographic algorithms properly requires specific training and expertise.